# Turn off translations for unittest

Tags: python, pylons, python-unittest

I have some python code like

```
from pylons.i18n.translation import _

def get_message():
     message = _(u"Translated message")
     # interesting code to test
     # [...]
     return 'result'
```

which I would like to unittest like this:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_get_message(self):
        assertTrue(get_message(), 'result')
```

Now running this test in nosetests gives me:

```
TypeError: No object (name: translator) has been registered for this thread
```

Is there a way to deactivate anything regarding translations when unittesting?

Comment: Have you tried mocking the `_()` function?

Comment: That code snippet above is your production code, right? What is your test code?

Comment: Well, this code is a simplified example ... why does it matter? I edited the question anyway.

Comment: @mocking: could you explain how to tell get_message() to use a mock instead of pylons.i18n.translation._?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your production code is in `my_module.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch
from my_module import get_message


class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_get_message(self):
        with patch("my_module._"):
            result = get_message()
            self.assertEqual("result", result)
```

With the `patch` your test changes the `_()` function to a `MagicMock()` object. Documentation [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html).

**NOTE:** `mock` is part of the standard library from Python 3.3 and onwards. Otherwise you should install it first using `pip install mock`.

Comment: Looks good, but outside of simplified questions it will give lots of problems if _ returns nothing ... how to replace it with a function that just gives back the string? As I understand patch only patches classes?!

Comment: ```with patch("my_module._", return_value='Not important')``` will at least make sure it returns a string.